# Using openpyxl cannot create XLSX

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I tried the below code. I tried opening on Excel but I was getting that the file is damaged and then repaired the file to read it. How do I remove the issue of xlsx repair when xlsx is opened.

```
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook

def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
  csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
  for row in csv_reader:
    yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

filename = 'WS_Data_0_2019_09_25_215340128516.csv'
reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# lets just save 10 rows in a xlsx
i = 0
for row in reader:
  if i < 10:
    ws.append(row)
    # print row
    i = i+1 

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Comment: on line ws.append(row) instead of row insert some dummy data. say ws.append('test') and check if xlsx file opens. then we can narrow down the problem that the data is not proper. If that is indeed the case, then the data from csv is wrong. So you can debug the unicode_csv_reader function.

Comment: If the file has non-ASCII in it then you need to open it with the correct encoding.

Comment: @abhlib that won't work with openpyxl, you'll immediately get an exception.